# Mac OS X 10.6 executable not found without full path

Tags: macos, bash, path

I just installed Apache via MacPorts. It seems that my Mac was absolutely confused about which version of the Apache executables to run.

After moving the Apache executables that ship with the Mac to a directory that is not listed in the `PATH` variable, trying to run the `httpd` built by MacPorts fails even though the correct directory (`/opt/local/apache2/bin`) is listed in the `PATH` variable.

If I navigate to the directory `/opt/local/apache2/bin` and type the command `httpd` I still get the error message

> -bash: httpd: command not found

If I type the command with the full path `/opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd` it works fine.

I've run the command `alias` to see if something was clashing but the only thing listed is:

```
alias wget='curl -O'
```

How do I find what is intercepting the command and preventing the executable being found in the directory, even when I'm inside the same directory?

By the way, the `httpd` file is executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin  442496  9 May  2012 httpd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. The current directory never belongs to the `PATH`. For this reason, even if you're inside `/opt/local/apache2/bin`, you cannot simply type `httpd` because Bash will only look in your `PATH`.

So, therefore you would have to type `./httpd` here.

To get Bash to look for executables in the MacPorts Apache directory, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/apache2/bin:$PATH
```

This will also result in binaries from that directory taking precedence over any other binaries with the same name that might come later in the `PATH`—check this with `which -a httpd`.